# Cannot get correct IP for user using PHP

Tags: php, geo

I am trying to get the country from an IP address.
The problem is that the users IP does not show up on some computers. Some users that test it get an IP but others don´t (on the same WiFi network).

This is my code. What is wrong?

```
function VisitorIP()
{
    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']))   //check ip from share internet
    {
      $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    }
    elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']))   //to check ip is pass from proxy
    {
      $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    }
    else
    {
      $ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    }
    return $ip;
}

$ip_address = VisitorIP();

$geodata = file_get_contents('http://api.ipinfodb.com/v3/ip-country/?key=0000&ip=' . $ip_address . '&format=json');

$decoded = json_decode($geodata);

$country = strtolower($decoded->countryCode);
```

Comment: Could always take a look at phpBB. They have a pretty complete method for grabbing the user's IP despite various conditions (including proxies).

Comment: `var_dump($ip_address)` for a visitor that does not give you one. What's in there?

Comment: Visitors *must* have an IP address, otherwise they couldn't receive a response. You should also exclusively use `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`, all other values are not confirmable and possibly bogus.

Comment: What do the users who "don't get an IP" get when you call VisitorIP? Every TCP connection **MUST** have an IP, so your function should return something. However, you ARE blindly trusting that the CLIENT_IP and FORWARDED_FOR variables are set properly - they're use-provided data and can be forged/faked.

Comment: BTW, the [phpBB3/common.php](https://github.com/phpbb/phpbb3/blob/c73ff606d4fcd578784739b72b3b0c1c37737430/phpBB/common.php#L195-204) code highlighting the IP lookup.

Comment: @deceze: That's not universally true. For instance, if your webserver is behind a load balancer, REMOTE_ADDR will be the load balancer's IP, and that's when X_FORWARDED_FOR comes in to play.

Comment: @Tyler That entirely depends on the load balancer's configuration etc etc. If you are in such special circumstances, you'll know it. For 99% of developers, the client's IP will be in `REMOTE_ADDR`.

Answer (score 0):

> What is wrong?

Everything.

The only IP available to the server is one stored in the $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] variable.
So, you have to use this one, not various HTTP headers of obscure source.

Comment: I need the IP-address of the user visiting my website and not the server ip.

Comment: it is named **REMOTE** ADDR if you didn't notice.

Comment: Ok sorry. But $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] does not give usable IPs in many cases.

Comment: Quite contrary, all these *HTTP headers* you were trying to use, aren't usable in many cases. While REMOTE_ADDR **always** contains correct IP address. Anyway, it's the only reliable info you have. You may wish to invent another Internet if you don't like it, but that's how it works at the moment. I won't say it's such "unusable" though. For the geolocation purposes it is pretty good. Got any statistics to show one of these "many cases"?